# Android XML problems with 3 linearlayouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got some trouble with layouts inside my page. I want make a dialog with 6 radio buttons, ImageView, and 6 seekbars and confirm button. But if i add a button i can't see it. It allways samwhere disapiard.
Here is sampe, what i want to make:
http://prntscr.com/3ywtnt
I think the seekbars take over to much place and than button fall down ...

Here is code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="8"
    >



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/blur"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Blur" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/outer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Outer" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/inner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Inner" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/pencil"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pencil" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/emboss"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Emboss" />
                           />

        </RadioGroup>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/widthImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        >
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:fillViewport="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutSeekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="16" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ime1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Width" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vrednost1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Width text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vrednost2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar2"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ime3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Width text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vrednost3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ime4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Width text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vrednost4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ime5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Width text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vrednost5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ime6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Width text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vrednost6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />





      </LinearLayout>

     </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

     <Button android:id="@+id/btn_ok1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"

                android:text="Ok"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use android:layout_weight in your xml and create a view

Comment: i add code :) but it is vary long :(

Comment: try taking scroll view and then add your XML code there

Comment: i am add scrollview in code. But tihis is for dialog, the button must be fixed. RadioButtons and imageView must be fix and in the seekbars i add scroll view ...but scroll view is to big :( i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
activity_main:
================

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="8" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/radiogrouplayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/blur"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Blur" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/widthImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="70dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/outer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Outer" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/inner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Inner" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/pencil"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pencil" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/emboss"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Emboss" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottombar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radiogrouplayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="false" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutSeekbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:weightSum="2" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Width text" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vrednost2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="10" />

                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:weightSum="2" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Width text" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vrednost2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="10" />

                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:weightSum="2" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Width text" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vrednost2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="10" />

                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:weightSum="2" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Width text" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vrednost2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="10" />

                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:weightSum="2" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Width text" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vrednost2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="10" />

                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:weightSum="2" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Width text" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vrednost2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="10" />

                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:weightSum="2" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Width text" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vrednost2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="10" />

                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:weightSum="2" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Width text" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vrednost2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="10" />

                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:weightSum="2" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Width text" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vrednost2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="10" />

                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:weightSum="2" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Width text" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vrednost2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="10" />

                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:weightSum="2" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Width text" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vrednost2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="10" />

                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:weightSum="2" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ime2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Width text" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vrednost2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="10" />

                            <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottombar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ok1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:text="Ok" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```